# I can't print value in array with nodejs and ejs

Tags: ejs

As my title of question.
I can't print value of var myArray. Plz help me. I am begin to nodejs, ejs.

index.js:

```
res.render('index',{
    nickName: 'My Nick',
    fullName: 'My Name',
    myArray: [
        myClass = 'nodeJs',
        mySchool = 'Home School'
    ]
});
```

index.ejs

```
<div>My Nick is: <%= nickName %></div>
<div>My Name is: <%= fullName %></div>
<div>My Class is: <%= myArray['myClass'] %></div> // can't print
<div>My School is: <%= myArray['mySchool'] %></div> // can't print
<div>My Array is: <% myArray.forEach(function(value){ %>
    <%= value %>
<% }) %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to assign an array you can write like this

```
myArray: {
    myClass: 'nodeJs',
    mySchool: 'HomeSchool'
}
```

then on index.ejs view call it like this

```
<%= myArray.myClass %>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
myArray: [
    myClass = 'nodeJs',
    mySchool = 'Home School'
]
```

should be

```
myArray: [
    myClass: 'nodeJs',
    mySchool: 'Home School'
]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
myArray: [
    myClass = 'nodeJs',
    mySchool = 'Home School'
]
```

This is clearly not a JS code. Probably it should be like this:

```
myArray: {
    myClass: 'nodeJs',
    mySchool: 'HomeSchool'
}
```